# How to launch my flask app via nginx/uswgi reverse proxy

Tags: python, flask, callable

```
~/app_dir/
|-/app_venv/
|-/app_module/
   |-appy.py
   |-__init__.py
```

appy.py looks like:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.debug=True

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
        return 'World'

if __name__=='__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

then in venv and from ~/app_dir/ I run:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5800 -w app_module.appy
```

except I get a `callable not found` (it's not an import error as if I change the name of the file I'll get that straight off the bat)

How do I reference the `app` callable correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default callable for any WSGI-compliant server is named 'application', you've named yours 'app'. You can override this in uwsgi by passing it as the --callable parameter.

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:5800 --wsgi-file app_module/appy.py --callable app --processes 4 --threads 2
```